# Ember.js using HandleBars to create a src attribute in an iframe

Tags: iframe, view, ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm trying to write the following

```
<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/videoID"/>
```

But in Handlebars I'm doing this

```
{{#each Videos.videosController }}
  {{#view}}
    <iframe {{bindAttr src="videoId"}}/>
  {{/view}}
{{/each}}
```

The problem is the `videoId` attribute of my object is just an id and I need to convert it into the full URL so I have written a function to change the property on the object

```
Videos.VideoView = Ember.View.extend({
  content: null,
  videosEmbedUrl: function(){
    return "http://www.youtube.com/embed" + this.getPath('.video.videoid');
  }.property("video")
});
```

But I'm really confused about how to call that function....

Any pointers very welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of different ways you can construct your views.  If you are going to set up a view that depends on the data, you'll need to bind the data to the view.

http://jsfiddle.net/crw6g/

```
{{#each item in model}}
   {{#view App.YTVideoView contentBinding="item"}}{{/view}}
{{/each}}
```